# In Html how do I display a Bootstrap Badge onto an image itself

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a grid of images, and for each image I have two figcaption elements rendered as badges beneth each image (plus a 3rd that renders correctly as a hyperlink), what I really want to do is have the badges at the bottom of the image itself, but have no idea how to do this.

```
<div style="display:grid;grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 1fr));grid-gap: 5px;">
    <div>
        <figure class="figure">
            <a href="FixSongsReport00277_changes00041.html">
                <img src="../images/Antonin Dvorak; Itzhak Perlman, Daniel Barenboim, Samuel Sanders.jpg" class="figure-img" width="200" height="200">
            </a>
            <figcaption class="badge badge-secondary">
                12 files 
            </figcaption>
            <figcaption class="badge badge-secondary">
                0 files modified
            </figcaption>
            <figcaption class="figure-caption">
                <a href="FixSongsReport00277_changes00041.html">
                    Antonin Dvorak; Itzhak Perlman, Daniel Barenboim, Samuel Sanders
                </a>
            </figcaption>
        </figure>
    </div>
    <div>
        <figure class="figure">
            <a href="FixSongsReport00277_changes00029.html">
                <img src="../style/images/folder.jpg" class="figure-img" width="200" height="200">
            </a>
            <figcaption class="badge badge-secondary">
                27 files 
            </figcaption>
            <figcaption class="badge badge-secondary">
                0 files modified
            </figcaption>
            <figcaption class="figure-caption">
                <a href="FixSongsReport00277_changes00029.html">
                    Choir of Trinity College
                </a>
            </figcaption>
        </figure>
    </div>
```

e.g

[image]

Based on Olegs answer I now have

[image]

Comment: Do you have any CSS attached with this?

Comment: @Keith no just using standard Boostrap 4 stylesheets

Comment: so from the picture above, the badges are at the bottom of the image. Did you want them touching the bottom of the image or did you want them inside of the image at the bottom

Comment: @Keith I wanted them inside the image itself at the bottom

Comment: I think OlegNovo has it then as an answer unless you are looking for something else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CSS to make them on top of the image

```
.badge{
   position: relative;
   top: -3em;        
}

.figure-caption {
  position: relative;
  top: -2em
}
```

Here's an attached [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g1dmnzp3/1/)

Comment: Thanks, because image has a slight border I modified style to position: relative;left: +1em; top: -4em; and this seems to work quite well. Is this standard way or hack, I was originally assuming would add to the img tag tself ?

Comment: No problem, since the badges are outside the img tags it shouldn't affect the images at all. Using CSS to solve positional problems is usually the standard I would say. Using the em keyword is much more efficient than lets say the px keyword because different screen sizes have different pixels obviously. Only caveat to this in particular is if you decide to add badges to your page that you don't want to exhibit this behavior, but you can easily alter the .badge to a custom class and add it to all the elements you do want to have exhibit this behavior.

Comment: Thankyou, because image has a border -3 was too tight, but -4em bit too much, any suggestions, see 2nd screenshot in question

Comment: you can also use decimals in the em keyword, try -3.5 em