# How do I use CSS relative positioning to allow two rows of info to be added with alignment

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

How do I use relative positioning to display two lines of info on an image without the order of info affecting each other.

So here the *Files*  badge to be displayed at the bottom of the image, with the *MusicBrainz* and * DIsocgs* badges above. Then *Files* and *MusicBrainz* should be at the same left alignment on the left of the image. The height is fine but unfortunately the badges are displayed in left to right aligned in the order they are added, I don't known how to fix this.

Also, I don't understand why hyperlink below the image is correctly aligned, why doesn't that get shifted over to the right ?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div style="display:grid;grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 1fr));grid-gap: 5px;">
  <div>
    <figure class="figure">
      <a href="FixSongsReport00398_byartistalbum00004_00001.html">
        <img src="../images/aElXsWl4r3Qd8Vr3aSYnHg==_thumbnail.jpg" class="figure-img" width="200" height="200">
      </a>
      <figcaption class="badge badge-success" style="position: relative;left: +1em; top: -5.5em;">
        MusicBrainz
      </figcaption>
      <figcaption class="badge badge-success" style="position: relative;left: +1em; top: -5.5em;">
        Discogs
      </figcaption>
      <figcaption class="badge badge-primary" style="position: relative;left: +1em; top: -3.5em;">
        9 files
      </figcaption>
      <figcaption class="figure-caption" style="position: relative;top: -2em;">
        <a href="FixSongsReport00398_byartistalbum00004_00001.html">
                        Nelson; Reed; Dupré; Gigout; Wills; Widor; Grainger; Karg-Elert; Weinberger: Pomp &amp; Pipes!
                    </a>
      </figcaption>
    </figure>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: concerning the two badges `MusicBrainez ` and `Discogs` where do you want them to be ? they are already aligned to the left

Comment: @Dadboz they are fine, the trouble is that '16 files' should be left aligned with MusicBrainz

Comment: It would be great if you could post a working snippet or give us some link so we can inspect. Did you try float property?

Comment: @DanishIqbal I have given the relevant html code snippet, im not a css expert, dont know about float, approach is from another question I had when I only had one row of data - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57042978/in-html-how-do-i-display-a-bootstrap-badge-onto-an-image-itself

Comment: Can you show us the relevant css? Also, I can't tell you how much I suffer to see all those `relative` position..

Comment: @MoshFeu The only CSS clases I am using are bootstrap 4, I only using relative because suggested by someone else so if you have better solution please share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to answer you by using the information you gave us. There are probably other more elegant solutions, but I will try to answer your question with a quick answer. I will also not discuss the semantics of the elements in this answer. You should also use classes instead of the tag names for the CSS selectors I will present below, ok? But I will try to make the answer as simple as possible.

You have siblings (all "figcaption" tags are in the same level). One way of controlling them independently if by using:

```css
figcaption {
  position: absolute;
}
```

Absolute elements are positioned relative to a parent with a defined position. Thus, you will need to add a position to the figure:

```css
.figure {
  position: relative;
}
```

Now you can control the badges with `top` and `left` as you are doing.
Example: https://jsbin.com/goqaqemudu/edit?html,css,output

The solution before has a major issue: you need to control the second green badge by hand. If you have more or less letters, they will be a bit strange. You can solve this issue by grouping them in a div:

```html
<div class="badges-line">
  <figcaption...
  <figcaption...
</div>
<div class="badges-line">
  <figcaption...
</div>
```

You will need to update the CSS to use such classes instead.

Another suggestion is to use float (this is a completely new suggestion). If you increase the margin of the second green badge, the blue badge will float to the next line when there is no enough space on the right. If you are curious to see what I am trying to say, see the example below and increase the value of the margin from `0.2em` to `0.4em`: the last label will float to the next line.

https://jsbin.com/ceqaqoxiji/edit?html,css,output

Of course, both solutions need some polishment. I also recommend to use another tag than `figcaption` for the badges. For me it does not sound semantically correct (but this is another discussion).

Comment: Thankyou that is a good explanation, I will try to implement. Its seems to be your initinal solution is better than using float (which seems like more of a hack)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, here is my approach.

1. Wrap all the "overlaps" element into one box (`div`) so you will have to deal with only one element.
2. Use `position: absolute` for it so it will not break the other elements layout. In short, even though `position: relative` allow to "move" the elements the browser still "keep" their original place and other elements will flow only after them ([read more about that](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-use-the-position-property-in-css-to-align-elements-d8f49c403a26/)) Notice that in this case, the image's "container" (`.figure`) should get `position: relative`.

I also moved out the link `.figure-caption` outside of `.figure` because that I think that it's better to the image "container" to contains only the images and the "floating" elements and not the "statics" (like the link).

So here is my suggestion:

```css
.figure {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
}

.figure .badges {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div style="display:grid;grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 1fr));grid-gap: 5px;">
  <div class="item">
    <figure class="figure">
      <a href="FixSongsReport00398_byartistalbum00004_00001.html">
        <img src="../images/aElXsWl4r3Qd8Vr3aSYnHg==_thumbnail.jpg" class="figure-img" width="200" height="200">
      </a>
      <div class="badges">
        <figcaption class="badge badge-success">
          MusicBrainz
        </figcaption>
        <figcaption class="badge badge-success">
          Discogs
        </figcaption>
        <figcaption class="badge badge-primary">
          9 files
        </figcaption>
      </div>
    </figure>
    <figcaption class="figure-caption">
      <a href="FixSongsReport00398_byartistalbum00004_00001.html">
            Nelson; Reed; Dupré; Gigout; Wills; Widor; Grainger; Karg-Elert; Weinberger: Pomp &amp; Pipes!
      </a>
    </figcaption>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsbin.com/godaqal/2/edit?html,css,output

Let me know if something is not clear.

Comment: HI, thanks but I ran your fiddle and the badges appear below the image when they should be within it

Comment: Sorry, didn't update it as I did in the snippet inside the answer. Anyway, I updated it.